# Ebean sort by different date

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I´d like to get a sorted list with java bean.

I got two fields in my Postgres db **creation_date** and **update_date**, I want a list sorted by whatever date is newer.

creation_date default is now(), update_date can be null

So if update_date is null the creation_date should be used as the sort value.

I want to create the following output:

created 27.12.2017 13:00

updated 27.12.2017 13:05

created 27.12.2017 14:00

created 27.12.2017 15:00

updated 27.12.2017 16:00

Comment: how could ever creation_date be greater than update_date? anyway, you may want to look at the sql instruction "order by": ```ORDER BY update_date NULLS LAST, creation_date```

Comment: How about the MAX() function?

Comment: well you can create an event and this creation_date is newer then the update_date form an existing event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was…

```
List<Event> events = Ebean.find(Event.class)
            .orderBy("coalesce(update_date, creation_date) DESC")
            .findList();
```